# How to fix Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 12

Tags: ios, iphone, shell, xcode8

[Image of error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ER6.png)

When I try to achieve file for uploading to iTunes, I got this error. 
But I can use simulator in Xcode.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Rsync seems to be failing for you because of the embedded spaces in the name of your directory. Look [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8136) for similar problem.

If it is in your control, you could try to escape the spaces in the names of your directories/files.